# Google Indexing a WordPress page that isn't finished yet, should I make it private?

Tags: seo, wordpress, search-engine-indexing

I have a few web pages that I am working on. 
The pages will be ready to be added to a navigation in about a month.

Well, Google is already indexing those pages even though they are not ready to be seen yet. 
Should I ignore this or privately publish them?

Comment: What do you mean by "privately publish them"?

Comment: It's a WordPress website and the pages can be privately published, meaning you have to be logged into the webiste as admin to view. If not, you see a 404 error.

Answer (score 4):

If the pages are not ready to be seen yet, you should mark them as private so they stay out of the Google search index. Only pages that are ready for other people to view should be in the search index, because the search index is designed to surface pages so they can be seen by the public.